# Laravel: Issue with relationship?

Tags: php, laravel

I'm beginning to think why did Laravel implement relationships to their framework, they've never worked for me and their a huge stress to fix when they break. This is the 5th time my relationships are returning null, even when ensuring I've set them up properly?

```
class UserStats extends Authenticatable
{
    protected $table = 'habbo_user_stats';
    public $timestamps = false;
    protected $guarded = ['id'];

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'id');
    }
}
```

And

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    protected $table = 'habbo_users';
    public $timestamps = true;
    protected $guarded = ['id'];

    public function stats() {
        return $this->belongsTo(UserStats::class, 'user_id');
    }
}
```

although, when calling

```
{{ $user->stats->some_column }}
```

`stats` is returning null... `$user` isn't null.

Comment: Are you trying to setup a one to many between users and user stats, User hasMany UserStats? If so your relationships are wrong. Change `return $this->belongsTo(UserStats::class, 'user_id');` to `return $this->hasMany(UserStats::class, 'user_id');`

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to define the owner of the relationship too. Ie:

```
public function stats() {
   // $this->hasMany OR $this->hasOne, depending on your use case.
   return $this->hasMany(UserStats::class, 'user_id');
```

}

We need to know here, does the user have many userstats? or the userstats have many user records? what are you planning to do here?

Comment: then try doing it with the way i showed you in the answer, and tell me if it worked.

Comment: Your example shows making user a hasmany, yet user only hasOne? Did you mean make UserStats hasmany?

Comment: this section in the docs will help you: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many

Comment: yes, I'm sorry, under the UserStats class, in the user method, return $this->hasMany(User::class, 'id');

Comment: I guessed you meant that, I've just added that but calling `stats` on User still returns null.

Answer (score 0):

Here are things I noticed about your code

- Your database structure is wrong. (need migrations to verify this)
- Extending UserStatus from Authenticable
- you have guarded id
- Your relationships definitions are not correct.

To confirm we would need to look into the database structure and migrations.

If a userstat have many users and a user belongs to 1 userstat.

the migrations will be

**users table will have a user_stat_id and userstats table wont have a user_id**

the code will look like this.

UserStatus.php

```
class UserStats extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'habbo_user_stats';
    public $timestamps = false;
    protected $guarded = ['id'];

    public function users()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(User::class, 'user_stat_id');
    }
}
```

User.php

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    protected $table = 'habbo_users';
    public $timestamps = true;
    protected $guarded = ['id'];

    public function stat() {
        return $this->belongsTo(UserStats::class, 'user_stat_id');
    }
}
```