# Laravel: unable to access with?

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to access the `User` model but its returning empty?

```
$topOnlineTime = UserStats::with('user')->orderBy('OnlineTime', 'DESC')->limit(10)->get();
```

In view:

```
@foreach ($topOnlineTime as $user)
{{ number_format($user->username) }}
@endforeach
```

`username`belongs to the user model

```
class UserStats extends Authenticatable
{
    protected $table = 'habbo_user_stats';
    public $timestamps = false;
    protected $guarded = ['id'];

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(User::class, 'id');
    }
}
```

Here is the user model

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    protected $table = 'habbo_users';
    public $timestamps = true;
    protected $guarded = ['id'];

    public function userStats() {
        return $this->belongsTo(UserStats::class, 'id');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `UserStats` has many `User` records, you need to iterate over users too:

```
@foreach ($topOnlineTime as $userStats)
    @foreach ($userStats->user as $user)
        {{ $user->username }}
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 1):

Check my answer on [Laravel: Issue with relationship?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49081599/1409707)
as I think the result for your loop is returning null because your migrations and relations are not set correctly.

Below is the answer for that question from me. I think after fixing that @Alexy Mezenin's answer above( https://stackoverflow.com/a/49082019/1409707) will work.

Here are things I noticed about your code

- Your database structure is wrong. (need migrations to verify this)
- Extending UserStatus from Authenticable
- you have guarded id
- Your relationships definitions are not correct.

To confirm we would need to look into the database structure and migrations.

If a userstat have many users and a user belongs to 1 userstat.

the migrations will be

**users table will have a user_stat_id and userstats table wont have a user_id**

the code will look like this.

UserStatus.php

```
class UserStats extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'habbo_user_stats';
    public $timestamps = false;
    protected $guarded = ['id'];

    public function users()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(User::class, 'user_stat_id');
    }
}
```

User.php

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    protected $table = 'habbo_users';
    public $timestamps = true;
    protected $guarded = ['id'];

    public function stat() {
        return $this->belongsTo(UserStats::class, 'user_stat_id');
    }
}
```